# System.IndexOutOfRangeException adding image in itextsharp

Tags: c#, wpf, itext

I'm having this issue adding an image to a pdf using itextsharp:

```
System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
at System.util.zlib.Tree.d_code(Int32 dist)
at System.util.zlib.Deflate.compress_block(Int16[] ltree, Int16[] dtree)
```

The code:

```
 cb.BeginLayer(pdfLayer); 
 iTextSharp.text.Image img = TextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(memoryStream); 
 img.SetAbsolutePosition(
      (float)(((resBounds.X - rectPage.X) / pageInfo.Dpi * 72.0f) * pageInfo.PrintOptions.Scale), 
      (float)((pageHeight * pageInfo.PrintOptions.Scale) - ((resBounds.Y + resBounds.Height) / pageInfo.Dpi * 72.0f) * pageInfo.PrintOptions.Scale));
 img.ScaleAbsolute((float)((resBounds.Width / pageInfo.Dpi * 72.0f) * pageInfo.PrintOptions.Scale), 
      (float)((resBounds.Height / pageInfo.Dpi * 72.0f) * pageInfo.PrintOptions.Scale)); 
 cb.AddImage(img); 
 cb.EndLayer();
```

The error happens in line:
cb.AddImage(img);

Comment: Please provide relevant code of yours. Have a look at [How to ask questions on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: please provide the code block, where the exception occured.

Comment: Please update your question rather than posting the code in a comment. Also it would be most useful if you could provide a minimal and complete sample program that shows the error.

Comment: Furthermore, please share the image in question.

Comment: If you remove the positiioning and scaling does it still cause an exception?

Comment: It has been a day so without a response I'm going to assume this is an isolated incident from a possibly corrupt or invalid image and recommend closing.

Answer (score 3):

Try resetting the stream back to the beginning - I had this issue and managed to resolve it by doing this:

```
memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin); //go back to start
```

Something to do with some form of cursor position - silly but hey!